# how can l read data form firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I'm trying to push data to firebase database by userId  , even each user he can modify has post or has information . the pushed data is successfully , but the problem is when l am try to getting data in html dose not show .

database

[image]

html

[image]

code for getting data :

```
items: Observable<any[]>;
itemsRef: AngularFireList<any>;
  constructor(public fire: AngularFireAuth,public db: AngularFireDatabase) 
    {
        this.itemsRef = db.list(`report/`);
        // Use snapshotChanges().map() to store the key
        this.items = this.itemsRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
          map(changes => 
            changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
          )

        );

      }
```

html

```
 <ion-list *ngFor="let item of items | async"> 
    <ion-item-sliding>
      <ion-item>
        <h2>{{itemstitle}}</h2>
        <p>{{item.name}}</p>
        <p>{{item.username}}</p>
        <p>{{item.dateadded}}</p>
    </ion-item>

      <ion-item-options side="right"> 
        <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="deletReport(item.key)">
          <ion-icon  ios="ios-trash" md="md-trash" item-end large></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <button ion-button color="primary" (click)="updatereport(item.key,item.name,item.title)">
          <ion-icon ios="ios-create" md="md-create"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-item-options>

    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
```

my push data :

```
name :string='';
  title :string='';
  Email:string='';
  dateadded:string='';
  userId: string;

  reports: AngularFireList<any>;
  items: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase,public alertCtrl: AlertController,public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    public navCtrl: NavController,public fire: AngularFireAuth) {
     var newPostKey = db.database.ref().child('report').push().key;
    this.reports = db.list(`report/${this.userId=fire.auth.currentUser.uid}/`);

    console.log(this.userId=fire.auth.currentUser.uid)

  }

  formatDate (date): string{

    const day = new Date().getDate();
    const month = new Date().getMonth()+1;
    const year = new Date().getFullYear();
    return `${day}-${month}-${year}`
  }
// dateaddread(dateadded){
//   this.dateadded = this.formatDate(dateadded)
// }

  Publish(name,title,dateadded){
    if (name.trim().length === 0) {
      console.log(this.name);
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Error',
        message: 'Please fill report blank ',
        buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present(); 
    }else if (title.trim().length === 0){

      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Error',
        message: 'Please fill title blank ',
        buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present(); 
    }else {

      this.reports.push({
        name:name,
        title:title,
        Email:this.fire.auth.currentUser.email,
        dateadded:this.formatDate(dateadded)

      }).then(Newreport=>{
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'Successful',
          message: 'Successfully posted',
          buttons: [
            {
              text: 'Ok',
              handler: () => {
            let navTransition = alert.dismiss();
            // start some async method
            navTransition.then(() => {
            this.navCtrl.pop().then(data => {
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(FeedPage)

            });
       });
      return false;
    }
    }]          
    });

      alert.present()

      })
    }

    }
```

any idea please with simple code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.reports = db.list(`report/${this.userId=fire.auth.currentUser.uid}/`);

this.reports.push({
    name:name,
    title:title,
    Email:this.fire.auth.currentUser.email,
    dateadded:this.formatDate(dateadded)
})
```

and for displaying the data in HTML, you just need to modify your query to get only the data of logged in user

```
this.itemsRef = db.list(`report/` + fire.auth.currentUser.uid);
```

Comment: thank you for answer . but how can user modify only has own data ?! . because depending on you answer each users can modify has data by others . l want only user he can modified has own data !

Comment: push() function push the list of data as an array but here you want to create only single node for each user so you might have to replace push function with set and list function with object, I have edited my answer you can check for the same and here is the link of angular firebase https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/objects.md for more information

Comment: thank you very much for replying , l did what you told me . and is working fine . but if l push the data with `set` the user he can not push another data ! . he has to update or delete only one data . l want the user he push many data not only one data , my app content app blog . i dont know if you get my point !

Comment: then you will have to use push function instead of a set, bro, let me know one thing when you fetch data from the firebase you show only those data in HTML which the current logged in user have posted/edited not all the data of all users, am I right?

Comment: yes l have to use push not set . and yes your right . l get only those data in HTML which the current logged in user have posted/edited . even l try with another user its same .

Comment: you can see my problem in image [https://c.top4top.net/p_11122i5nf1.png] l want each user when he post in blog app can show list array in html but l got only one element

Comment: l got error `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null`

Comment: you have to pass userid in db.list(`report/` + userid), see firebase docs to how to get userid of logged in user

Comment: can l give you id code for anydesk to check my code remotely ?

Comment: l fixed last error , but still html is empty data !

Comment: yes show me your code on github or plnkr wherever you find easy

Comment: l am try to upload to github and plnkr  but dose not work , can you check my code remotely like timeviewr

Comment: this easy software for remote desktop [https://anydesk.com/remote-desktop] and this is for my code address 823132215

Comment: when i try to connect with your given address it is saying that client is offline and cannot be connected

Comment: create a zip file of your app folder and mail me farman@proprofs.com , I will try to solve your problem